# How to justify vertical axis on the right?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization, candlestick-chart

I need to take the labels for the vertical axis to justify at the right instead of left.

"this is just garbage that is useless just to fill up some space."

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
      // Treat first row as data as well.
    ], true);

    var options = {
      legend:'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

there are no standard config options for label alignment,
but you can move them manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
    ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
    ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
    ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
    ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
  ], true);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none'
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var labelIndex = -1;
    var labelWidth;

    var axisLabels = container.getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(axisLabels, function(label) {
      if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'end') {
        labelIndex++;
        labelWidth = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#label#' + labelIndex).width;
        label.setAttribute('x', labelWidth);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I saw that doing a search. To much work for nothing and I'll still be limited by a google lib. I coding my own candlestick chart. I'll take the time it needs but it will work exactly like I want. Taking shortcuts sometime aren't worth it on the long run. thanks anyways